# Decorator to tag functions as callable

Tags: python, decorator

I'm creating a function tagging system, to enable or disable functions based on tags:

```
def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs): pass

class Selector(set):
    def tag(self, tag):
        def decorator(func):
            if tag in self:
                return func
            else:
                return do_nothing
        return decorator

selector = Selector(['a'])

@selector.tag('a')
def foo1():
    print "I am called"

@selector.tag('b')
def foo2():
    print "I am not called"

@selector.tag('a')
@selector.tag('b')
def foo3():
    print "I want to be called, but I won't be"

foo1() #Prints "I am called"
foo2() #Does nothing
foo3() #Does nothing, even though it is tagged with 'a'
```

My question is about the last function, foo3. I understand *why* it isn't being called. I was wondering if there's a way to make it so that it is called if *any* of the tags are present in the selector. Ideally, the solution makes it so the tags are only checked once, not every time the function is called.

A side note: I'm doing this to select tests to run based on environment variables in `unittest` unit tests. My actual implementation uses `unittest.skip`.

EDIT: Added the decorator return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that if you decorate it twice, one returns the function, one returns nothing.

```
foo3() -> @selector.tag('a') -> foo3()
foo3() -> @selector.tag('b') -> do_nothing

foo3() -> @selector.tag('b') -> do_nothing
do_nothing -> @selector.tag('a') -> do_nothing
```

This means, in whatever order, you will always get nothing. What you need to do is keep a set of tags on each object, and check that whole set at once. We can do this nicely without polluting namespaces with function attributes:

```
class Selector(set):
    def tag(self, *tags):
        tags = set(tags)
        def decorator(func):
            if hasattr(func, "_tags"):
                func._tags.update(tags)
            else:
                func._tags = tags
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs) if self & func._tags else None
            wrapper._tags = func._tags
            return wrapper
        return decorator
```

This gives some bonuses - it's possible to inspect all the tags the function has, and it's possible to tag with multiple decorators or by giving many tags in a single decorator.

```
@selector.tag('a')
@selector.tag('b')
def foo():
    ...


#Or, equivalently:
@selector.tag('a', 'b')
def foo():
    ...
```

The use of [`functools.wraps()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) also means the function keeps it's original 'identity' (docstrings, name, etc...).

Edit: If you wanted to do some wrapper elimination:

```
    def decorator(func):
        if hasattr(func, "_tagged_function"):
            func = func._tagged_function
        if hasattr(func, "_tags"):
            func._tags.update(tags)
        else:
            func._tags = tags
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs) if self & func._tags else None
        wrapper._tagged_function = func
        wrapper._tags = func._tags
        return wrapper
```

Comment: Won't this cause the wrapper to get the tags in subsequent calls to the decorator?

Comment: @Lucretiel An extremely good point. Fortunately I think the wrapper is actually superfluous here, looking at it again. Edit: Fixed, and tested, pretty sure it works now.

Comment: I feel like we're getting so close. I haven't tested it, but it looks like it'll still be a problem- if a tag fails, the decorator returns `do_nothing`, which is passed to subsequent instances of `selector.tag`

Comment: @Lucretiel I knew there was a reason I put the wrapper in there. Better idea, just add the tags to the wrapper. Simplest solution.

Comment: Honestly, at this point I'd be willing to just use a class and `__call__`. The problem is that this is for use in the unittest module, which detects test cases by name, and I don't know if I trust using `wraps` on `__call__`

Comment: I'm pretty sure (again), it works now. It's not too bad - if you wanted you could do some wrapper elimination, but I doubt it'll really matter in most cases. I also think it's a much nicer idea to keep information about a function with the function - it means that if you need it elsewhere, it's infinitely easier.

Comment: You're updated solution is almost exactly what I'm going with. The only difference it that I move the if outside `wrapper`. I'm not expecting the tags to change after they're initially set, so it only needs to be called once. Basically, I return the `do_nothing` wrapper with `_tagged_function` set if the tags don't match, and just return the original function (with all tags set) if they do.

Comment: for curiosity: wouldn't `@functools.wraps(func)` already copy `_tags` form `func` to `wrapper`?? I haven't tested that myself (I know I should better do so;) , but from the docs I understand that it does so. So is this line redundant `wrapper._tags = func._tags`

Comment: Yes it does. I never knew that. I thought it only updated the name, module, and doc, but apparently it also grabs the `__dict__`

Answer (score 1):

Would that work for you:

```
class Selector(set):
    def tag(self, tag_list):
        def decorator(func):
            if set(tag_list) & self:
                return func
            else:
                return do_nothing
        return decorator


@selector.tag(['a','b'])
def foo3():
    print "I want to be called, but I won't be"
```

Comment: Note this will still fail in the original example of multiple decorator calls.